# How to apply styles on child component when the parent is active

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, inertiajs

So, I'm learning Vue.js with Inertia.js in Laravel and I can't figure out how to apply styles on children component when the parent is on active condition on particular route in Laravel.

So, as you can see here I have a Navlink with a button as it's children and I want to apply  a background color to the button if the Navlink is in active condition as I shown on the highlighted text here :

[button with background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdfGY.png)

How ever I have also imported a Navlink component that automatically generated when I install Inertia.js and Vue.js on Laravel.

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const props = defineProps({
    href: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
    },
});

const classes = computed(() =>
    props.active
        ? 'inline-flex items-center py-2 border-b-4 border-t-4 border-indigo-400 text-sm font-medium  leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
        : 'inline-flex items-center pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
);
</script>

<template>
    <Link :href="href" :class="classes">
        <slot />
    </Link>
</template>
```

There's an active condition for the Navlink, but I don't know how to use the same thing for the button inside the Navlink. I really appreciate for the answer, thank you!

I've tried putting condition on every button using this method that I got from Inertia.js documentation

```
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
<Link href="/users" :class="{ 'active': $page.url === '/users' }">Users</Link>
```

But I wonder is there any better and simpler way to solve this problem? Thanks!